# How to adjust which python is called in terminal

Tags: python, macos, macos-high-sierra

macOS High Sierra 10.13.2

For a variety of reasons I have both python 2 and 3 installed on my mac. When I enter "python" in terminal python 2.7 activates but I need python3 to open instead. Is there a way to change this and if so how?

Comment: type `python3`.

Comment: `python3` will invoke your default python 3 version.